# Django 3rd Party Auth Systems

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am considering a 3rd part Authentication system for logging in (new/old) users. Much like how StackOverflow authenticates it's users. This scheme is good as it frees me from doing authentication from my side. I need this -

1. Login using Google, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo, OpenID Authentication Systems.
2. Provide the same user logged in functionality as the default django auth system i.e. @login_required decorators should work

There seem to be some number of Django-apps out there which claim to solve this problem. Which ones are good?
Ex. [Django-SocialAuth](http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth/tree/master), [django-openid-auth](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-auth/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an all-in-one solution, I had good results with [django-socialregistration](http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration). It has auth backends for Twitter, Facebook and OpenID (Google, Yahoo!, ...).

Another possibility would be [JanRain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/) (formerly RPX) which provides a single point of authentication for all the major authentication providers. There's a 3rd party [django app](http://github.com/howthebodyworks/django-rpx) for it, but I can't say anything about its quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something simple try [this](https://github.com/simul14/django-googleappsauth)

Answer (score -1):

those are actually auth backends.

In other words, you're still using django.contrib.auth - you're just loading an extension to it.

Auth backends are pretty easy to write, so I would just take a look at the docs and then see if the code looks like something you'd be comfortable working on (for each candidate for a backend).

If you're afraid to change your codebase, you're in trouble.